# Android Force OkHttp Request Over Mobile Network

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Is a way to force OkHttp to do requests over the cellular network?

My app has certain requests that must be sent over the cellular network (3G, LTE, 4G, *not Wifi*). I'm using Retrofit and OkHttp for all the other network requests, so I would like to use it for these requests also. It looks like `ConnectivityManger.registerDefaultNetworkCallback()` could help but that only supports API 21+. I would like a solution for API 19+.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming API 21+,

```
Network network;  // filled in from ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory())
        .build();
```

you'll have to rebuild the `OkHttpClient` when the network goes away and comes back, but it's doable. You may be able to use a non-default network explicitly this way (some devices can keep the data connection up even when connected to and defaulting to WiFi).

On API 19 you may check `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` and refuse to operate if the type is WiFi, and check again from a `BroadcastReceiver` registered for [android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a solution for lower API than 21, you can try with `ConnectivityManager`.

You have this method `setNetworkPreference(type)` where `type` is either `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` or `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`. In your case is `TYPE_MOBILE`.

This method was deprecated in API 21+, you should check for current Android version.

Note that this call requires `android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` permission.